# Delete duplicate items in Excel (including original value)

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2007

How to delete duplicate items in excelsheet(column), where it has to delete the items which has more than one occurrence:

```
1  
2  
3  
3  
4  
4
```

If we use remove duplicate option, it will give distinct values, but what should be done to get only values

```
1  
2
```

Since 1 and 2 values are not duplicated and these two have only one occurance in a Excel(column)

Comment: In a column, add a CountIf function: `=CountIf($A$1:A6;A1)`, and repeat the function along the column for each value of yours. Then filter the rows where this column equals to 1.

Comment: You can also use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates, do a filter for a color and delete that color. I think this is a good question.

Comment: is problem solved now? check the solution....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Follow Below Steps.

1. Consider you have data in `column A`
2. Write formula as `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,0,1)` in `column B`.
3. Apply Step 3 for all rows that are there.
4. Wherever you have duplicate data, you will see `1` in `column B` else you will see value as `0`. :)
5. Go To menu `Data` and apply filter for `1`. Those are the rows that are duplicate. Want to delete it?? Delete it :)

### Here is the [demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuDxo8hGuxaQdDZteHFiWm9lVXZyWFdaY244ODJuVGc#gid=0)

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A1)=1;0;1) if anyone gets an error in Excel ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

How about Conditional Formatting --> Highlight cell rules --> Duplicate values
Duplicate values now highlighted. Apply filter, sort by colour, delete all highlighted cells - that only leaves unique values.

Answer (score -1):

The COUNTIF macro is pretty slow for long columns. If you need something faster, you can do the following:

1. Sort the column of values in column A.
2. In Column B next to it, add the formula =IF(A1=A2,0,1)
3. Double-click the + icon at the bottom right of the formula's selection box to apply the formula to the whole column.
4. Add a filter while both the columns are selected.
5. Click the column B filter arrow button to show only values where Column B = 1

This will flag all of the transitions from one value to the next with a 1. Then the filter will only show those rows with a transition. The resulting filtered column A will contain only the unique values.